# Is asking about "the best and most beautiful design for dashboard large buttons" on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Is asking about "the best and most beautiful design for dashboard large buttons for android" on topic?

Or asking about up to date and common design for dashboard UI for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are certainly views and trends about what is 'best' or 'beautiful' in terms of design style, the answers to these questions are usually subjective or contextual, so they are not really suited to the UXSE forum or format of questions.

In terms of up-to-date and common design patterns, there are already many references that you can find from existing or similar questions (and answers). But if you want to ask about a particular type of design concept or style then it can fall within the scope of what is acceptable.